# How to get ORDER BY working within a nested select statement

Tags: mysql

Can't figure out why ORDER BY within a nested select statement doesn't work... For example:

A normal select order by statement works fine:

```
select id from posts where zid=5 order by id desc;
```

but a nested select order by statement does not work?:

```
select id from posts where zid in (select id from zids where qid=57 order by id desc);
```

Is it not allowed? It doesn't produce any errors, but changing from ASC & DESC changes nothing...

Comment: Does it matter if it doesn't? Why not move the ORDER BY to the outer SELECT?

Comment: yeah it matters if it doesn't. If i move the order by to the outer select, i get a different order where posts are showing according to when they were created rather than the order required.

Comment: Inner SELECTs don't determine the order of outer SELECTs, as you have discovered, put additional fields in your outer ORDER BY to get the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not allowed?

NO it's not and moreover it doesn't make sense ordering the nested result set at all. You should be having the `order by` in outer query like

```
select id from posts 
where zid in (select id from zids where qid=57)
order by id desc;
```

Again, you can consider replacing your existing query with a `JOIN` query like

```
select id from posts 
JOIN zids ON posts.zid = zids.id
where zids.qid=57
order by zids.id desc;
```