# MySQL select top n records per group nested

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get top n (2 for now) rows from MySQL (Version: 5.6.29 and 10.1.28-MariaDB). 
I have seen simple examples on SO or elsewhere ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group),[example2](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group))
The problem is that my query is more complex and it doesn't seem to be working well.

I have tables as seen on the diagram (some fields are removed for brevity):

[image: EER]

Each purchase_item can be either coupon, purchase_offer or subscription_plan (one is valid and the other two are null). Each of these have `subscription_days > 0`.

Innermost SELECT works as expected by itself. Second SELECT doesn't work as expected (even if I remove the outer select), `purchase_rank` is often the same for the same `customer_uuid` as if the innermost select doesn't sort by customer_uuid.

Any ideas?  I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133321/how-to-get-order-by-working-within-a-nested-select-statement#45133357) that ORDER BY doesn't work well in nested query perhaps that is the problem in my case? How should I do this then?
Or maybe query optimizer is doing something weird? I tried replacing CASE with IF and the result it the same. 
Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    uuid,
    purchase_offer,
    subscription_plan,
    coupon,
    customer_uuid,
    payment_date,
    subscription_days,
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id,
            uuid,
            purchase_offer,
            subscription_plan,
            coupon,
            customer_uuid,
            payment_date,
            subscription_days,
            @purchase_rank := CASE @current_customer
                WHEN customer_uuid THEN @purchase_rank + 1
                ELSE 1
            END AS purchase_rank,
            @current_customer:= customer_uuid AS current_customer
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            pi.id,
            pi.uuid,
            pi.purchase_offer,
            pi.subscription_plan,
            pi.coupon,
            pi.customer_uuid,
            p.payment_date,
            IFNULL(po.subscription_days, IFNULL(sp.subscription_days, cpo.subscription_days)) AS subscription_days
    FROM
        purchase_item pi
    JOIN purchase p ON p.id = pi.purchase
    LEFT JOIN purchase_offer po ON pi.purchase_offer = po.id
    LEFT JOIN subscription_plan sp ON pi.subscription_plan = sp.id
    LEFT JOIN coupon cp ON pi.coupon = cp.id
    LEFT JOIN purchase_offer cpo ON cp.purchase_offer = cpo.id
    WHERE
        p.status = 'COMPLETED'
            AND pi.customer_uuid IS NOT NULL
            AND p.payment_date IS NOT NULL
            AND (po.subscription_days > 0
            OR sp.subscription_days > 0
            OR cpo.subscription_days > 0)
    ORDER BY pi.customer_uuid , p.payment_date DESC) AS temp) 
AS pu
WHERE
    pu.purchase_rank <= 2
ORDER BY pu.customer_uuid , pu.payment_date DESC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: I found [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/). It appears to be working fine even on MySQL, not just MariaDB. Nested query needs `LIMIT <large number>` which creates temporary table. So [Cataklysm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47078891/5350141) is partially correct, but it doesn't work with smaller numbers (at least not according to my testing).

Here is corrected part of the code:

```
...
ORDER BY pi.vehicle_uuid , p.payment_date DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615) temp) pu
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of limitation of MySql Queries you could simply add a `LIMIT 0, 2` at the end of your statement.

For detailed information about the limit statement, feel free to check [this documentation with realtime example.](http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

---

**EDIT I**

For example: Get the first n results from a statement:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase
ORDER BY payment_date ASC
LIMIT n
```

And the other way around:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase
ORDER BY payment_date DESC
LIMIT n
```

If you know you want to skip the first n results of your query, you can start `LIMIT`at a given offset. As example, we want to skip the first 10 results:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase
ORDER BY payment_date DESC
LIMIT 10, n
```

Comment: Thank you, but that won't really do. If I use `LIMIT` it will limit all records, not last 2 records per group (`customer_uuid`). Unless I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: @RokMirt Last 2? I thought you need the first n results of your group? But eitherway that shouldn't be a problem, since you can choose where to start the limit, you just need to know how many results there are, or work with another `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Cataklysim Sorry, yes I meant first N. However, if I do it your way, query won't return the first N for every group (group is `customer_uuid`) but it will take the first N from ALL groups. 
Example: I have 3 purchases from `customer1`, 3 purchases from `customer2` and 3 purchases from `customer3`. Purchases were done in the same order.  So if I want first `N=2` purchases from each customer and do it as you said (the innermost `SELECT ... LIMIT 2`) it will only return the 2 purchases from `customer1` instead of 6 purchases (2 per customer)

Comment: @RokMirt oh, I get it know. I didn't understood it quite right... maybe add the tag `greatest-n-per-group` and you need to rebuild your statement... but I don't know how. So my "Answer" is wrong. Sorry.